# Using Selenium to verify presence of certain css computed elements for form fields

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I would need a good way to verify error icon is shown for mandatory form fields when submitted with empty input using selenium 3 webdriverjs.

Below is part of DOM trace when error is thrown if mandatory field is left blank & form is submitted.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 " style="display: inherit;">
<div class="vx_floatingLabel_complex vx_floatingLabel_active vx_has-
error-with-message  ">
<label for="testerAccountData_phone">Telefone</label><div 
class="vx_form-control" data-label-content="Telefonnummer" style="">
<input type="tel" maxlength="20" value="" autocomplete="off" 
name="/testerAccountData/phoneNumber" id="testerAccountData_phone">
</div><span class="vx_form-control-error-icon icon icon-small icon-
critical-small"></span><span></span><span></span></div></div>
```

I am looking at validating multiple fields in the form,

Q: how do I use selenium to check if error icon appears for the field. i'm not sure if i can use getAttribute function, as error icon seems to be part of CSS element?

=> class="vx_form-control-error-icon icon icon-small icon-critical-small">

Comment: to verify the icon which seems to be assigned via CSS in your case, assert the computed style `background-image` returned by `element.getCssValue("background-image")`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you confirm that you can select the element. Selenium has the element.isDisplayed() api that can help you determine if the element is visible

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L2160

//untested code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className('vx_form-control-error-icon')).isDisplayed();
```